# How to check all checkbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

i have a few checkboxes an I want funcionality to check or uncheck all checkbox. Here is a class .cs and xaml code. How to add funcionality for check or uncheck all?

```
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler IsCheckedChanged;
    private bool isChecked;

    public WorkStep(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsChecked = true;
    }

    public WorkStep(string name, bool isChecked)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnIsCheckedChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnIsCheckedChanged()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = IsCheckedChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
    }
```

and xaml:

```
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: I usually make a list : List<Checkbox> myBoxes and add the boxes to the list.  Then I can simply write code to enumerate through the list.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like shown in the class below:

```
public class myClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _IsChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set
        {
            _IsChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Then I would bind the property `IsChecked` to all of my checkboxes like shown below in the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox3" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

In the `MainWindow` class make a new instance of the class where the `IsChecked` property is located (in my case `myClass MyClass = new myClass()`). Then add the newly created instance `MyClass` to the DataContext of your MainWindow (`DataContext = MyClass;`). I use a button control in this example to check and uncheck all of my checkboxes. If the value of the property `IsChecked` is true all of the checkboxes are checked and if it's false all of the checkboxes are unchecked. The `MainWindow` class is shown below :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = MyClass;
}

myClass MyClass = new myClass();

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyClass.IsChecked)
        MyClass.IsChecked = false;
    else
        MyClass.IsChecked = true;
}
```